# How to block communication between 2 different subnets?

Tags: iptables, routing, firewall, bridge

I have a scheme like this

router 192.168.2.254/24

eth0-192.168.2.1

br0

eth1-192.168.4.1/24

user- 192.168.2.2/24

and connected eth0 and eth1 like this to allow packets pass through
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth0
brctl addif br0 eth1
dhclient br0

and the user can ping to router directly but I want to block that pinging

I tried even

iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP

iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP

and user still can ping to router, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please show us your `iptables -nvL` with the non-working rule so we can actually see if there's any error in it.  It would also be nice to know if you can ping the router from that server.

Comment: there is no more iptables that is all I want to do

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is but you **will not** get any useful answer if you refuse to provide the details that could clarify **your mistake**.

Answer (score 1):

A bridge is to connect two interfaces that are in the **same** subnet.

If you have different subnets and want them to communicate with each other, you need to enable routing `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward` but by default this is not enabled, so they will not be able to talk to each other.

Edit: Bridging two interfaces in different subnets will work but it's not a traditional setup. If you want to keep your configuration that way, you'll have to use `ebtables` instead of `iptables` to block the traffic.

Comment: I tried to use ebtables but when I use them the router suddenly dies and computer are not able to communicate each other until I restart it

Answer (score 0):

You  should define your iptables with router ip address.Any users cant ping router ip address.Your example was general iptables rules.Dropping icmp protocol was right to prevent ping.

Comment: mmm how should I drop icmp protocol? I did a iptables -A INPUT --p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j DROP.

Comment: Its correct iptables rule.Why did you ask again? If you are not sure.You can search it from Internet.

Comment: because they do not work..

Comment: you should use your router ip address on iptables rule not used general iptables rule.You meant to drop all ping to your router ip address.Why dont you read some iptables tutorial?